# Android Alarms every other day (or other non day specific interval)

Tags: android, alarm-clock

In the default Android clock app, you can set an alarm for specific days of the week, but not a more flexible schedule such as repeating every other day or only the third Thursday of the month.

Is there a better alarm app that offers that flexibility? Using the calendar allows more sophisticated repetition but only notification, not alarm functionality.

[Note: cross-post from [Android.StackExchange]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246496/set-alarm-for-every-other-day) as this may be a more appropriate forum for this question

Comment: If I remember correctly, [Business Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal) allows this. But the free version comes with quite a bunch of trackers (17), [Business Calendar 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal) with even more (21); only the paid [Business Calendar Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro) is free of them.